# In Django/Python, how can I find out which method called my method?

Tags: python, django, stack-trace

I would the first line of my method to be:

```
print "this method was called from "+filename_and_linenumber_of_code_that_called_it.
```

Is it possible to throw an exception, catch it immediately, and print a stack trace when a method is called?

Answer (score 6):

When i just want to make the code crash at some point to see the traceback, i just put "`crash`" in the code. Because it's not defined, it will crash, and i will see the traceback in django's exception page. If in addition, i use `runserver_plus` command provided by `django-extensions` (requires package `werkzeug`) then i get **[an AJAX shell at each frame of the stacktrace](http://getfile5.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-09-05/ymxEEmumJIgetrtmddIAjydxzeHFDDgqwzjhugkJEzExiDtCbuEijxiebtjD/debug-screenshot1.png.scaled1000.png)**.

I understand you problem and I'm going to propose a professional method for dealing with this kind of problem. **What you are trying to do is called "[debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)"** and there are tools for that.

**Quickstart**:

1. run `pip install ipython ipdb`
2. replace the print statement in your code by `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`
3. execute your code in runserver, it will pause and spawn a python shell where you can send **command "`up`" to go to the previous stack frame (code that called your code)**. Type `l` if you want to see more lines of code.

**Longer start**: well actually i wrote a [an overview of tools which help debugging python and django](http://blog.yourlabs.org/debugging-python-and-django-code).

I disagree with other answers which propose to add more elaborate print statement. **You want to be a good developer: you want to use a debugger**. Be it werkzeug, pdb/ipdb, or GUIs, it doesn't matter as long as you can use it.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll definitely have to look into debuggers.  Right now I do all my debugging by relying on print statements in my code.

Comment: Yep, i've seen that in your previous question - which ends by "how to debug this". Learning about debuggers is definitively going to help you !!! Note that you can put "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" anywhere in your code and it's native python. The interface is just a little crude at first sight that's why i recommended ipdb ;) The thruth is that **graphical debuggers are really awesome**, but are harder to setup in python. Anyway, i think that's a very good question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that using each print statement for debug purpose **KILLS A KITTEN SOMEWHERE IN THE WORLD**. You should use logger.debug rather than print in these cases.

Answer (score 4):

No need to throw an exception to view the stack. I have this nice function (it's not perfect, but I think it works) that may help you:

```
import inspect
def log(error):
  frame, filename, ln, fn, lolc, idx = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
  print "Error: " + error + " " + filename, ln, fn
```

It prints the message followed by the name of the file that the parent function is in, then the line number of the call in this file, and then the name of the function. I hope it'll help you :)

Comment: Thanks. However, I am getting an error that says "ImportError: No module named introspect"

Comment: It should be `import inspect`.

Comment: Oh sorry! That was supposed to be "import inspect", my bad!

Answer (score 1):

This is CPython specific:

```
import sys

def func():
    frm = sys._getframe(1)
    print 'called from %s, line %s' % (frm.f_code.co_filename, frm.f_lineno)

def test():
    func()  # line 8

test()
```

Prints:

```
called from /path/to/script.py, line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

A debugger like **pdb** can be helpful. Refer below snippet.

```
def f4():
    print "in f4"

def f3():
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    f4()
    print "in f3"

def f2():
    f3()
    print "in f2"

def f1():
    f2()
    print "in f1"

f1()
```

Once entered in pdb console, the **up** command can be entered to jump to the caller function.

Refer below screenshot.[image]